# header lags behind when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I tried to find something about this on the net, and although it's a minor issue, I feel as if it impacts the site experience. Furthermore, depending on the browser or speed of your computer, you may not notice this problem.

The issue is I have a fixed header on my site. When scrolling up or down, it seems to lag or drag behind... it stays fixed at the top, but while you scroll it jutters and drags at a different pace.

You can see for yourself, [here](http://melbourneweb.co/portfolio).

It's doing my head in - it seems to only happen on the portfolio page, and not the home page.

Comment: this isn't happening in firefox, but it is in chrome

Comment: i can't reproduce it, but i find another bug http://clip2net.com/s/iHsphQ

Comment: once the page is fully loaded in chrome, the lag doesn't happen, it's good then.

Comment: Can't reproduce it either. If you only used position: fixed then there should be no problem. If the fixed position is emulated by a JS plugin, that could cause lagging. Also on mobile devices lag might occur.

Comment: as @CarolMcKay said, problem is in Chrome, but when i open Developer Console - problem is gone. Is it possible that `height:auto` case problem?

Comment: @CarolMcKay @user2167382 I tried removing the `height:auto` and no luck. As soon as you open developer tools and change something, the problem disappears. I'm only using position:fixed.

Comment: @user2167382 - the other bug you found - I'm trying to keep the code as clean as possible and implement the grey bar with an :after pseudo-element, but when I set 100% width it inherits the padding of the parent element. I tried setting 100vw but it was too wide (doesn't subtract scrollbar width when calculating viewport width).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same issue on Chrome. Solved it by adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to the header element in my stylesheet;

There is good [article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/) regarding this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: YOU DID IT! This is the correct solution. I had given up months ago and only just saw this - finally managed to fix it! Thankyou so so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because you're trying to do a fair bit on the window scroll event.

Every time a scroll event fires you've got a parallax scroll function that modifies elements with the `parallax` class (though there don't seem to be any actual elements with that class). You're also checking whether to add the class that changes your header background.

One thing you can do to improve performance is to do as little as possible inside the actual scroll function.

```
//Menu contrast happens when user scrolls down

// Save 4 jQuery select operations and 2 function calls per scroll event
var myNav = $('nav');
var heightDiff = $('#bg1').height() - myNav.height();

// Use global variables in the scroll function
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset < heightDiff)
    {
        myNav.removeClass('contrast');
    }
    else
    {
        myNav.addClass('contrast');
    }
});
```

You can do something similar with the parallax loop as well.

```
// Save 2 jQuery select operations and one function call per scroll event
var htmlHeight = $('html').height();
var parallaxElems = $('.parallax');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollpercentage = window.pageYOffset/htmlHeight;
    var moveoffset = 350*scrollpercentage; // set parallax coeficcient
    parallaxElems.css('background-position-y',(50-moveoffset)+'%'); 
});
```

Keep in mind that if you use JavaScript to add new elements to the DOM or modify existing elements, you may have to compute your global variables again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I implemented the performance fixes as you said but I've noticed that the issue also only occurs when I use my trackpad or mouse wheel to scroll - if I click and drag the scrollbar, no lag. I'm not sure if the performance fixes have improved it at all, but they may well have.

Comment: Considering this, it's probably not a performance issue.
Using chrome developer tools, if I uncheck then check a css property on the nav element (effectively changing nothing) - the lag disappears.

Absolutely stumped.